# How to skip BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter for public endpoints?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot 2.x application with oauth2 login; I also have a public endpoint, "/public", for which I expect no login or security whatsoever.

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/public", "/oauth2/**", "/login/**", "/logout").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .oauth2Login();
```

At some point someone POST /public with the `Authorization` header set to "Bearer some-invalid-token-here". The `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` processes the requests and fails; what should I do to have `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` not processing my request?

Answer (score 0):

I found that one could use this configuration to skip entirely the spring security, hence `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` too:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        log.debug("ignoring spring security for: /public");
        web.ignoring().mvcMatchers("/public");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // other configurations here if any
    }
}
```